# Google Place API usage limitations and billing

Tags: billing, google-places-api

I have developed one app in which i have used the Google Place API. This is what places doc says about limitation.

**The Google Places API has the following query limits:**

1. Users with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period.
2. Users who have also verified their identity through the APIs console are allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card is required for verification, by enabling billing in the console. Your card will not be charged for use of the Places API.

**So my question is that if i enable billing for Place API then its free? Is it really true?**

Comment: See official up-to-date websites and API documentation for these questions

Comment: As far as I understand the current pricing model you get a free monthly credit of USD 200 which maps to certain amount of free usage per service (or SKU  in Google terms). See price sheet: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you will have what they are saying. I have done that, so I can confirm... If you put your credit card info, you are letting them know that you are a verified user, and that therefore you won't misuse their services.

And for the second question, we are talking about Google here. It is really true, you won't be charged, they can make money from other sources :)

**EDIT:**

Actually, if you need more than the "verified" option, it seems you can contact them as stated by Thor Mitchell (Product Manager @Google) in this topic at Quora: [Pros and Cons of Places API](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-Places-API)

> "The limits on use (after identity verification) is 100,000 requests
>   per day, and we're happy to talk to developers who need more about
>   their requirements."

Comment: Hi....Need some more information for this. Suppose the number of request exceed 100000 then Google will start charging or they will take permission from me and then start charging?

Comment: They won't charge for it, there is no information available on charges, this should be stated very clearly in their usage policies. You have to complete the review form and get/not get an approval for an increase: http://places-quota-uplifts.appspot.com/

Comment: Is this still the case in 2015?

Answer (score 12):

As of today, the limit is [150,000](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/) free requests per day, but [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits) is hard to make sense of in terms of how they bill overage.

Comment: It's just stop working if you are over 150K. If you need higher limit the only option is the Premium plan.

Comment: Right, you have to purchase credits but the pricing for that is not clear, at least for me.

Comment: I don't think the price of Premium plan is exposed in the documentation. You should contact the sales team to get this information: https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/

Comment: If i don`t add any credit card information and i want to use free version of nearby search api as in the limited no of requests how i do that/

Comment: @AsadMukhtar currently you need billing enabled account {if you're using latest Andriod SDK for google places } to fetch result from user 's selection. otherwise, API will respond like this . 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400963/google-places-autocomplete-cant-load-search-results

Comment: I contact to Google Platform Help that was such other type of error, and i already add billing account and already enabled.

Answer (score 8):

Latest update **March 2019**:

**"For an overview of pricing for the Google Maps Platform products, please see the [Pricing Sheet.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?__utma=102347093.803954946.1551756399.1551758908.1551758908.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1551758908&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1551758908.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)%7Cutmccn=(direct)%7Cutmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=125576330&_ga=2.237053059.2045150526.1551756604-803954946.1551756399)**

**To learn more about how Google Maps Platform APIs are billed, please see [Understanding billing for Maps, Routes, and Places.](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use)"**

[image]