# Google Places Autocomplete Can't load search results

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to implement the Google Places Autocomplete API sometimes I am able to get location list but sometimes I get **"can't load search results"** message. Can someone pease help me with the issue.

Comment: got any solutions ? same error for me as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This issue have a few possible reasons:

- [No billing account associated to the project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project)
- [If you are still using the old Places
  SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)
- [If you reach your quota limit(e.g. self imposed cap
  usage)](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage)
- [If your app is not properly
  restricted](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)

If any of the above doesn't fix your issue, it would be best to reach out to the [support team of the Google Maps Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support) as this error commonly has something to do with your configuration in the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com) wherein only the support team of Google Maps Platform can assist you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks actually there was not billing account was associated with the project. Associating billing account solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i already added the billing service also then get the same error then i added the api key in gradle file and then its works for me

Added your api  RNGP_ANDRIOD_API_KEY=***** in gradle.properties

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer, eve if it is right, try to explain a little bit.

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet ?

Comment: @Ujash Sadariya Could you please provide a snippet

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above still doesnt work, and if you happen to be using an emulator to run the app, try uninstalling the app, then re-installing it when you run the program in android studios.

*Background info:
I happened to encounter this issue on my emulator despite doing everything mentioned above, but when I tried downloading the app onto my phone, I found it working there so I tried uninstalling the app on my emulator and it worked after.*