# google place Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, google-maps

I have read there ([Google Places Autocomplete Can't load search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400963/google-places-autocomplete-cant-load-search-results))
how to solve an issue about troubles with Google Place and have decided to use version 2.0.0 because it recommended. Initially, I tried to use version 1.1.0 in my project. But had no success. After you type more than 3 characters an options in the search list have evaporated or works unstable.

So my project can't be built with version 2.0.0. With version 1.1.0 project has build. I'm confused.

It's working: 
**implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'**

But when I switch to version 2.0.0
**implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'**

I see the error:

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:524)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:143)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor198.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

How can I update the version to 2.0.0?

Comment: Can you please try the solutions in this related thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Comment: I have read and a little bit misunderstand maybe. What is from written there can be useful in my case?

Comment: You're reporting the same error so I'd suggest trying out the accepted solution first, as well as the others if still not working. Also please post your build.gradle and manifest.

Comment: manifest:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfmVA0szYS5yoqSsfpY-xnomrgYOhpiw/view?usp=sharing

build.gradle
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uKRS9s2JWFN-o3XK7xDOlxwm79vS5u2J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the issue lies in your app not having migrated to androidX yet.

Comment: Please see my answer below, should the issue persist please let me know and I'll troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate your app to AndroidX to use v2.0.0. Google's [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) states:

> Version 2.0.0 of the Places SDK for Android now depends on
>   AndroidX. Beginning with this version, the old support library will no
>   longer be supported. In order to retain compatibility, you must
>   migrate your projects to use AndroidX.

If you're using Android Studio, you can [refactor](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio) your app to migrate to androidx very easily.

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: I think you are right. I don't use AndroidX and it is the main reason for my issue. I will try to migrate to AndroidX. My first attempt was failed. In my case, simple actions were trying to go to the main menu and select  Migrate to AndroidX was initiated new troubles :) Thank you. I will struggle.

Comment: You're welcome! Do please keep me posted, and if you cannot migrate to androidX let me know and I'll try to help you with that too.

Comment: Thank you. Your recommendation was useful!

Answer (score 0):

The advice about migration to AndroidX support library was useful. Some preliminary actions were necessary done before. At zero I have updated Android Studio to the newest version. At first, I removed .gradle and gradle directorys. At second I have changed 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4' -> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'. After that, I selected from the main menu Migrate to AndroidX. I pressed "Do Refactor" button and have got a message:

```
Cannot perform refactoring operation.
There were changes in code after usages have been found.
Please perform usage search again.

Would you like to rerun the search now?
```

I repeated the refactor and it was ended normally. I have change version of Places to 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0' and my project has been built successfully.