# Google Places Autocomplete is not working Sometimes in Xamarin Android Project

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am implementing **Google Places Autocomplete** in my Xamarin Android project. (This is not a Xamarin Forms Project).
When I search first time, the autocomplete works properly but consequent searches do not work properly.

[image]

Even if the autocomplete works, if I select an item, it will not call `OnActivityResult` function and get back the above screen again.

Even these posts did not solve my problem

- [Google Places Autocomplete Can't load search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400963/google-places-autocomplete-cant-load-search-results)
- [Android onActivityResult not called / triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019711/android-onactivityresult-not-called-triggered)

I have not set a billing account but I dont think that is the problem because it works sometimes. How can I solve this issue?

(Please note this is not a duplicate question since I could not find any questions like this)

This is the code I am using to open Google Places Autocomplete view

```
private void BtnLocationOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Place.Field> fields = new List<Place.Field>();

    fields.Add(Place.Field.Id);
    fields.Add(Place.Field.Name);
    fields.Add(Place.Field.LatLng);
    fields.Add(Place.Field.Address);

    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.Overlay, fields)
        .SetCountry("US")
        .Build(this);

    StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Once the item is selected `OnActivityResult` function need to be called

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        if (resultCode == Android.App.Result.Ok)
        {
            Place place = Autocomplete.GetPlaceFromIntent(data);

            txtLocation.Text = place.Name;

            googleMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(place.LatLng, 15));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code and see how you are implementing it?

Comment: Hi @Juanes30 I have added the code and updated the question

Comment: I faced the same situation you explained above.
But here's a tutorial I followed and it worked for me. I was using Xamarin.googleservices.places and I realized later that it was deprecated and used the same lib you're using above Xamarin.Google.Android.Places. Kindly check that Url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9WHrc3ffYY

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling billing on your project is mandatory for the Places API (or any other Maps API) to work. Otherwise you are limited to 1 request per day.

Follow Google's [get started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#procedures) to create a billing account and link it to your project.

Also make sure that the [Places API](https://cloud.google.com/console/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com) is enabled on your project too.

Hope this helps!