# How many Google Places Search/Details requests per day can I make for free?

Tags: javascript, api, frontend, backend

I have enabled billing for my Google Places API credentials, I'm using Javascript SDK, after reading the docs on usage and billing I'm even more confused, I don't want to have a surprise 2k ticket this month just because I exceeded the limits so can anyone explain to me:

How many Place Search request  requests per day can I make?

How many Place Details requests per day can I make?

For Foursquare API they are much straightfordward with limit usage, I have 5000 premium and 95000 basic requests per day, easy right? For places it seems they tried to make the docs as vague as possible in order to cash in.

Usage and billing:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Place API usage limitations and billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161672/google-place-api-usage-limitations-and-billing)

Answer (score 0):

Users with an API key are allowed 1000 requests per 24 hour period. Users who have also verified their identity through the APIs console are allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period.
I am marking this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161672/google-place-api-usage-limitations-and-billing#:%7E:text=The%20Google%20Places%20API%20has,requests%20per%2024%20hour%20period.).